# What is the best way to implement swipe navigation with angular2 router?

Tags: angular, animation

I want a full page app with tabs on top and want to make it such that whatever content the user is seeing in view, they can "swipe the div to the left" to look at the next view (next route in the tab). What is the best way to do this to look animated/transitioned/smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use routerAnimation to do this. By swipe or click on tab user will navigate to next route and you can define animations and bind to host so whenever user will enter to a route it will be animated.